# Need to append <ul> with items from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a function that appends my `<ul>` with each item from my array but can't seem to get the syntax right. Any tips?

```
<body>
    <ul class="messages">
    </ul>

    <script>
    function Display(message){
    for(var i=0; i<message.length; i++){

    $("ul#messages").append("<li>"+message[i]+"</li>");

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages` is a class, not an id. This it needs to be

```
$("ul.messages").append("<li>"+message[i]+"</li>");
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNLDM/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Right now you're jQuery is selecting messages as if it were an Id, however, it's a class.

```
<body>
    <ul class="messages">
    </ul>

    <script>
    function Display(message){
    for(var i=0; i<message.length; i++){

    $(".messages").append("<li>"+message[i]+"</li>");

    }
    }
```